# Why doesn't rails 2.1 catch exceptions with rescue_from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-exceptions

in my ApplicationController, I have

```
rescue_from StorageExceptions::AuthorizationFailed, :with => handle_auth_error

def handle_auth_error
  redirect_to error_path(403)
end
```

but the code is not catching this error. I have checked that what is being caught is NameError with message: "uncaught throw `StorageExceptions::AuthorizationFailed'"

Why is this and how can I catch the actual error?

Comment: It seems that for some reason, the error is converted to NameError somewhere in the stack. I can't think of why, 'cos I can't find where it is raised as NameError.

Comment: and what in the name of hades is 'perform_action_without_rescue'? I cannot find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the `rescue_from ..., :with => ...` syntax working in my Rails (2.3.8) app, too - I solved it by using the alternative `rescue_from ... do ... end` form:

```
rescue_from(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken) do |e|
    #TODO: Flash something?
    logger.error "! Invalid authenticity token when accessing #{request.url}"
    render(:template => 'sessions/new', :layout => 'pre_login')
end
```

I never figured out why the first form never worked, though...

Hope this helps!